# How can we check the response of UDS message through CAPL?

Tags: capl, uds

I have written a basic program to send a UDS message in CAPL, But I don't know how to take the response inside the testcase function.

Below is the code snippet

```
includes
{
  
}

variables
{
    message 0x639 read;
}

void maintest()
{
    tc1();
}

testCase tc1()
{
    read.dlc=0x08;
    read.byte(0)=0X02;
    read.byte(1)=0x10;
    read.byte(2)=0x03;
    output(read);
    testStepPass("OK");
}
```

Comment: Don‘t do that by using raw CAN commands. Better use the diagnostics feature set. Either use a CDD/ODX or Setup basic diagnostics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the previous comments, it is recommended to use the Diagnostic Features.

If you wish to use raw frames, then there is a function for waiting for the response message.

```
TestWaitForMessage(0x649,100);
TestGetWaitEventMsgData(res_msg);
```

The `res_msg` will be having the byte values of the response.
You can access it by `res_msg.byte(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use diagnostic module from CANoe?

You can add your own diagnostic console under `Diagnostics (or Diagnostics & XCP) tab -> Diagnostic/ISO TP` and set up your own console (you need to configure things like target address, diagnostic layer etc.).

After that all the functions needed for CAPL you can find in help `press F1 in CAPL Browser -> CAPL Functions -> Diagnostics CAPL Functions`.

Comment: I have tried that also I can tell exactly what iam tried. I have added basic UDS console and tried to send Extended session command (10 03) , but getting timeout response

Comment: But sending it manually gives you a positive response? Check if configuration is all proper. Check if timeout time on the bottom of the configuration screen isn't lower than what you get response normally (and just set it to be higher).